# how to enable roaming data programmaticaly?

Tags: android, roaming

i have a problem. I bought google nexus 7 (3g version) on ondroid 4.2.2 and i want to enable\disable roaming data programmaticaly. how do i do that?

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean st = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isRoaming();
```

this code check state of the roaming.

May i enable/disable this function from my source code or it is possible only preferences activity of the mobile settings?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the link to back it up. But I thought Android doesn't allow apps to change those settings.